# Which type does keyword auto default to?

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently trying to get my head round C++11 and have just discovered the auto keyword.

I was wondering with the use of auto which type would it default to given certain values.

For instance with an integer value of say 65535, would that default to an unsigned int, signed int, unsigned short etc? Or does it just remain as auto and not need to default to anything?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: 65535 is an `int` because that's an integer literal. Others can be specified through use of suffixes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't "default" to anything. `65535` is an `int`, by definition, so `auto` is `int` in this case. For example, if you did `65535L`, then it's a `long`, and `auto` would be a `long`.

Note that the above is considering a "typical" system. If `65535` is too large for `int` (perhaps maybe because `int` is 16-bits on this other system), the compiler will give it a larger type so that `65535` it "fits" into its own data type, (in this case, `long`), in which case `auto` becomes `long`. The exact rules regarding the type of an integer literal are given in section 2.14.2 of the standard (thanks Benjamin Lindley and James Kanze). The important part to remember, though, is that there are specific, clear rules as to what the type of something is, so `auto` never has to guess or "default" to anything.

Comment: Cheers, that was I was expecting, but I just wanted clarification. Thanks

Comment: On a system where `int` is 16 bits, it would be a `long`.

Comment: In other words, the compiler is not _free_ to promote it to another integral type.  The constant has a very definite integral type.  There's no freedom involved, and no promotion either, in the sense the standard uses promotion.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The part of the standard I read (section 2.14.2, paragraph 3), says "it *may* have that extended type" (it doesn't say "it *shall* have that extended type"), which to me indicates some freedom. It's entirely possible there's another part of the standard which I've missed that says it "shall have that extended type," in which case if there is I'd appreciate if you could help me find it. I'll edit to clear up the ambiguity of my use of "promote," though.

Comment: @Cornstalks: See paragraph 2 of the same section.  Paragraph 3 refers to *extended integer types*.  But extended integer types don't come into play here.  Extended types are implementation defined integer types.  For example, an implementation may have an `int128_t`, though such is not required by the standard.  65535 is guaranteed to be able to fit in a `long`, which is a *standard integer type*, not an *exended integer type*.  Extended integer types only come into play when standard integer type options are exhausted.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I completely missed that paragraph. Thanks for helping me to see that! I'll edit my answer.